# Unable to install SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP 7.52 on OPENSUSE VM

Tags: virtual-machine, opensuse, sap

I am trying to install SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP 7.52 on OPENSUSE VM, but when i run install.sh it starts and after sometime stops installation without an error or a warning, which makes it difficult to me to get what's going on !

Last lines of console after exiting from instalation:

```
Added the license file /sybase/NPL/SYSAM-2_0/licenses/SYBASE_ASE_TD.lic
SAPCAR: processing archive /media/sf_abap/server/TAR/x86_64/SAPHOSTAGENT42_42-20009394.SAR (version 2.01)
SAPCAR: 45 file(s) extracted
```

I have donwgraded the version of OPENSUSE from 15.5  to 15.2 but it does not solve the issue.  any support is appritiated thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted the software vendor yet?

Comment: No sir, i've published the question here first in the hope that perhaps someone has already encounterd the same issue

Comment: It's a really long shot... And it's commercial software for which customer/tech support must tell you 1. where it can or can't run and other system requirements; and 2. After confirming the system requirements are met, help you, their customer, troubleshoot what's wrong specifically in your environment.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by setting VboxGuestAdditions.iso as a primary device in Oracle Virtual Box (It can only be set if vm is turned off)